# How to substract some participants data from main data frame in R

Tags: r

I have TWO data frames DF1 and DF2 of following participants and variables for example.I want to substract DF2 from DF1.

```
DF1     =   Part Age  B.P 
            1    23   87
            2    34   76
            3    23   75
            4    25   75
            5    24   78

DF2      =  Part  Age B.P
             3    23   75
             5    24   78
```

I want to substract DF2 from DF1 so the output should be like

```
FinalDF = Part   Age   B.P
           1      23    87
           2      34    76
           4      25    75
```

i am using

```
FinalDF <-setdiff(DF1,DF2)
```

But answer is not correct in R.. My original data is so huge arounf 600,000 sample size and i have to substract 115 from them but not happening.. This formula only substract 45 although they should remove 115 sample data..

Reproducible Data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
  Part = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  Age = c(23,34,23,35,34),
  B.P = c(87,76,75,75,78))


DF2 <- data.frame(
  Part = c(3,5),
  Age = c(23,34),
  B.P = c(75,78))
```

Comment: In `dplyr` you can do `anti_join(DF1, DF2)`

Comment: @Ben don't you have to specify the column? `anti_join(DF1, DF2, by = "Part")`

Comment: If you don't specify `by` it will assume all columns: `by = c("Part", "Age", "B.P")` ... if you try it out, it will show this information in output...

Comment: By using anti_join I am facing following error.Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Mb

Comment: then you could use try to use `filter` with `%ni%`. first use ` ` '%ni%` <- Negate('%in%') ` then try `DF1 %>% filter(Part %ni% DF2$Part)`

Answer (score 0):

In base R. The following assumes that DF1 has the always has all the part numbers, always starts at 1, and there are no repeated or skipped part numbers. Those restrictions can be worked around if your data does not conform to them, let me know.

```
RowsToRemove <- match(DF2$Part,DF1$Part)
mydata <- DF1[-RowsToRemove,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `subset` + `%in%`

```
DFout <- subset(DF1, !Part%in%DF2$Part)
```

such that

```
> DFout
  Part Age B.P
1    1  23  87
2    2  34  76
4    4  35  75
```